# How to tell model (Multiclass Classification using Logistic Regression) is overfitting?

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, classification, natural-language, overfitting

I'm training a logistic classifier to classify 5 classes using scikit-learn. The data isn't extremely imbalanced (class 1: 27.7%, class 2: 19.4%, class 3: 17%, class 4: 19.6%, class 5: 16.2%). I'm trying to tune the number of features and the regularization/penalty coefficient based on the macro average F1-score, but **I don't know how to interpret the macro F1-scores of the predictions from the training and validation set to understand whether my model is overfitting or not**. Moreover, should I use the F1-score or just regular accuracy is fine (given my data isn't super imbalanced)?

[image: This is a picture of my macro f1-scores from the training and validation set for a specific number of features and different penalty coefficients]